# Regex returned unexpected result after matching

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink, preg-match

I'm using regex to match a link, but the result is missing a significant piece. After it matches, it misses the 'amp;' in the link for some reason. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

```
$link = "/w/index.php?title=Category:English_verbs&amp;pagefrom=AFFAMISH%0Aaffamish#mw-pages";
$regex = "~^/.+~";

preg_match($regex, $link, $match);

print_r($match);
```

**Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => /w/index.php?title=Category:English_verbs&pagefrom=AFFAMISH%0Aaffamish#mw-pages )
```

^---this result is missing the `amp;` between `verbs&` and `pagefrom`.

**Expected Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => /w/index.php?title=Category:English_verbs&amp;pagefrom=AFFAMISH%0Aaffamish#mw-pages )
```

Comment: You may be seeing the output on a browser that decodes the html entities. Here's your code running normally http://ideone.com/h7xhhr . You can always use the php functions `html_entity_decode()`  or `htmlentities()` to respectively decode or  encode html entities.

Comment: view the source code, not the rendered output in your browser. or add plaintext headers `<?php header("Content-Type:text/plain");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It's not](https://3v4l.org/5ACNv). You're probably just looking at the output in a browser, where if a `Content-type` header of `text/html` is sent, the browser will process it as HTML (*and thus `&amp;` becomes `&`*).

Try viewing it in CLI to avoid this problem or use `header('Content-type: text/plain')` if you insist on viewing it in your browser.